# Can't deploy Rails app to Heroku; complains about postgres when I'm not using any DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've built my first rails app and I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku but the app just crashed every time I push. When I try to log into the rails console, this is what is see:

> Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.6183
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in
>   `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the
>   gem is not loaded. Add`gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its
>   version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

I'm not even using any database in my app.
This is what my database.yml file looks like:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#

development:

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:

production:
```

Can someone help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: I saw this on Heroku articles for Rails 4.x : "To run on Heroku your app must be configured to use the Postgres database, have all dependencies declared in your Gemfile, and have the rails_12factor gem in the production group of your Gemfile." and this  : "If already have an app that was created without specifying --database=postgresql you will need to add the pg gem to your Rails project.". It seems that it's mandatory that it must have a `pg` gem whether or not you use a db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that heroku will either rewrite database.yml or set environment variables that rails will pick up automatically.

You need to actually stop Activerecord loading:

To do this you replace `require "rails/all"` at the top of config/application.rb

With

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

You'll also need to remove anything in config/initializers or config/environments that references activerecord

Answer (score 0):

I believe heroku uses its own automatic database configuration ignoring your database.yml which explains why it still expects postgres. I'm not sure you can do anything about it other than include the gem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your gem file.

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```